# Transpose Table with information

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I need to transpose this view (in sql)

[image]

into this view:

[image]

any solutiion?

Comment: Check out UNPIVOT.

Comment: Please say which DBMS?

Comment: Please read [ask] in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select location, planning_product, '2016-05-16' as MondayDate, [5/16/2016] as ROP
from t
union all
select location, planning_product, '2016-05-09' as MondayDate, [5/9/2016] as ROP
from t
union all
. . .
```

Note that the column names need to be escaped.  Some databases uses double quotes, others use backticks or square braces.

Comment: I follow your solution but it is not showind the numbers....it is showing only 0 values

Comment: select [ Location], [Planning Product], Cast('05/23/16' as datetime) as MondayDate, 05/23/16 as SUKadj_TDOS from [dbo].[Producttdos] union all
select [ Location], [Planning Product], Cast('05/30/16' as datetime) as MondayDate, 05/30/16 as SUKadj_TDOS from [dbo].[Producttdos] union all....

Comment: @PriscilaEstala . . . You have to escape the column names.  Otherwise `05/23/16` is treated as a numeric calculation.  You might use `"05/23/16"` or `[05/23/16]` depending on the database.

Comment: I get Invalid column name '05/16/16' with double quotes,backticks or square braces.

Comment: btw I am using sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the table name is **Tab** and that you have the following 3 dates (you can replace them with your own): [1/16/2015], [2/16/2015], [3/16/2015]

```
WITH Unpivoted (PlanningProduct, Location, [Monday Date], ROP)
AS(
    SELECT PlanningProduct, Location, CONVERT(datetime,MondayDate) AS [Monday Date], ROP
    FROM 
        (SELECT Location, PlanningProduct, [1/16/2015], [2/16/2015], [3/16/2015] -- add your dates
        FROM Tab) pvt
    UNPIVOT
        (ROP FOR MondayDate IN ([1/16/2015], [2/16/2015], [3/16/2015])) AS unpvt -- add your dates
)
SELECT PlanningProduct, Location, [Monday Date], SUM(ROP) AS ROP
FROM Unpivoted
GROUP BY PlanningProduct, Location, [Monday Date]
```